# Cannot install python module: command '/usr/bin/llvm-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, macos, llvm-gcc

Can someone help me with that issue, I have found many post reporting the same error but no solution worked for me. I got the same error with multiple modules.

I am setting up os X 10.7. I have Xcode 4.3.2 installed, I have download the Command Line Tools. 
I have installed python2.7 by following this tutorial: http://www.thisisthegreenroom.com/2011/installing-python-numpy-scipy-matplotlib-and-ipython-on-lion/#lion.

Now I am trying to install some other modules like igraph using the following command: pip install python-igraph and I get this error:

lipo: can't open input file: /var/folders/XXX (No such file or directory)

error: command '/usr/bin/llvm-gcc' failed with exit status 1

I get the same error for multiple package :(

I have already tried to :
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" 
and to follow the things given in :
http://waqasshabbir.tumblr.com/post/19073648382/llvm-gcc-4-2-exe-error-on-mac-osx-lion-when-building

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to install igraph doing:

```
brew install igraph
sudo pip install python-igraph
```

However I still have the problem for other modules !!!! 
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar issue with Linux and pip. Using "sudo pip install...." solved the problem for me. Maybe this works for OS X too.

Good luck.

Comment: I get the same kind of error: 
lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccNIjAfX.out (No such file or directory)

error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit status 1